# Problem in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

```
create procedure InsertQuestionEntry
@round_name varchar(40),
@question varchar(100),
@answer varchar(40),
@option1 varchar(20),
@option2 varchar(30),
@option3 varchar(30)

as
begin
insert into QuestionEntry(Question,Round_Name) values(@question,@round_name);
declare @quesion_id int

exec @quesion_id= select Question_ID from QuestionEntry;

insert into Answer(Question_ID,Answer,Option1,Option2,Option3) values(@quesion_id,@answer,@option1,@option2,@option3);
end
```

Here I want to retrieve the `Question_ID` from table `QuestionEntry` and use that `Question_ID` to another table `Answer`

But this didn't work.

So how can I use above way?

please help me

Comment: What didn't work? did you receive an error message?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
insert into QuestionEntry(Question,Round_Name) values(@question,@round_name);
declare @quesion_id int

exec @quesion_id= select Question_ID from QuestionEntry;
```

use the following:

```
DECLARE @quesion_id int
INSERT INTO QuestionEntry(Question,Round_Name) values(@question,@round_name)
SET @quesion_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: Actually, you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY`, otherwise you might end up getting a wrong identity value....

Answer (score 4):

You should not use ["exec"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) there.

What exec does is:

> Executes a command string or character
>   string within a Transact-SQL batch, or
>   one of the following modules: system
>   stored procedure, user-defined stored
>   procedure, scalar-valued user-defined
>   function, or extended stored
>   procedure.

You should use "set" or "select" instead of exec.

> `SET` can only assign one variable at
>   a time, `SELECT` can make multiple
>   assignments at once. When assigning
>   from a query if there is no value
>   returned then `SET` will assign
>   `NULL`, where `SELECT` will not make
>   the assignment at all (so the variable
>   will not be changed from it's previous
>   value)

You can find more info about when to use SET or SELECT here: [SET vs SELECT when assigning variables](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/01/390.aspx)

Sample:

```
set @quesion_id = (select Question_ID from QuestionEntry)
select @quesion_id = (select Question_ID from QuestionEntry)
```

But that's also wrong way to get identity value from inserted record. If you have N users execute a same procedure at a same time it can happen that you will get wrong value (from last inserted record).

To do this properly you should use [`@@IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) or even better [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx). More info: [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/).

After INSERT you can simply call:

```
SELECT @quesion_id = @@IDENTITY
--or
SELECT @quesion_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Also, check your Question_ID is configured properly. It should be set to auto increment.

Sample:

```
Question_ID int IDENTITY(1,1)PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

The 1's following the IDENTITY keyword indicate the SEED number (value for first record in table) and increment property (0 or 1).

Answer (score 3):

If your server's version is SQL Server 2005 or higher, you could also try something like this:

```
create procedure InsertQuestionEntry
  @round_name varchar(40),
  @question varchar(100),
  @answer varchar(40),
  @option1 varchar(20),
  @option2 varchar(30),
  @option3 varchar(30)
as
begin
  insert into QuestionEntry(Question,Round_Name)
  output inserted.Question_ID, @answer, @option1, @option2, @option3
    into Answer  (Question_ID, Answer,  Option1,  Option2,  Option3)
  values(@question,@round_name);
end
```